# Ubicacion dinamica de directorios especificos

Tags: python

estoy trabajando con un script de python que debe:

-Localizar dinamicamente uno o dos directorios.

-imprimir el contenido de los posibles ficheros en el directorio.

El directorio consiste en:

```
Carpeta madre
 |--Script.py
 |--archivo con la ruta
 |--Carpeta hija
     |--archivos
```

Para lograr esto,hice lo siguiente..

```
def paths_finder():
    home_pat = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/'
    while True:
        try:
            for base, dirs, files in os.walk(home_pat):
                if 'child_folder' in base:
                    rut = base + '/'
            os.chdir(rut)
            os.chdir('..')
            with open('the_path', 'w') as file:
                file.write(rut)
        except:
            print('directorio hijo inexistente')
            break    
        
        with open('the_path', 'r') as file:
            l = file.read()
            for line in l.split('\n'):
                if len(line) > 0:
                    with open(line + 'hola', 'r') as currentFile:
                       f = currentFile.read()
                    print(f)
                    return
```

*Disculpen la indentacion de la primera linea,pero asi me lo toma la pagina.

Lo hice de esta manera porque quiero ejecutarlo como un comando del sistema,a travez de un enlace simbolico en usr/bin para poner un ejemplo.
Sin embargo,esto tiene un problema..es un poco lento y cada vez que intente imprimir en pantalla la informacion solicitada el archivo the_path se reescribe cada vez..

Lo que busco es hacer algo asi..

```
def paths_finder():
    while True:
        try:
            with open('the_path', 'r') as file:
                l = file.read()
                for line in l.split('\n'):
                    if len(line) > 0:
                        try:
                            with open(line + 'hola', 'r') as currentFile:
                               f = currentFile.read()
                            print(f)
                            return
                        except:
                            print('directorio o archivos inexistente 1')
                            return

        except:
            try:
                home_pat = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/'
                for base, dirs, files in os.walk(home_pat ,
                    followlinks = False):
                    if 'child_folder' in base:    
                        print(base)
                        rut = base + '/'
                        with open('the_path', 'w') as file:
                            file.write(rut)
                
            
            except:
                print("error final directorio hijo inexistente")
                return
```

Donde primero trato de leer el archivo donde esta la ruta que necesito abrir para encontrar los archivos a consultar.
De no estar el archivo the_path,se lo crea y si el directorio no existe,se sale.
Estoy un poco bloqueado y no se como implementar el funcionamiento del segundo ejemplo en el primero..
Si alguien me puede guiar un poco,se los agradeceria.

> Solucionado,bastaba con agregar al path el directorio del script.sin necesidad de utilizar un enlace simbolico.